# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, usb, tls

Paid for and downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 TLS.
I have the "ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso" on a 4gb USB drive.

Question
How can I install the .iso file?  I think I need to convert the .iso file into a bootable USB ... however, I only have the "Ubuntu 16.04 TLS" from the original USB I bought, it wont load, something wrong with USB, it errors out ... but, the Ubuntu 16.04 TLS USB has an option to bootup Ubuntu to see if we like it ... (note: this is different from the install version).

Is there a tool I can access on the web, while in the Ubuntu test version, that will covert the .iso to a bootable USB?

Thank you,
Don

Comment: Paid for it? I thought it was free unless you order the DVD which you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the iso imagen from ubuntu.com page and use Rufus. It is free and easy to use. Rufus is a program that converts your iso image into a bootable usb....you can use any usb you want...Rufus formats it and makes it bootable.

hope it helps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)